# Locking bootloader after vendor build change

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader, xiaomi, miui

So, I have a Mi 10 Lite with the MIUI 12 EEA, and it's not the stock ROM but the Vodafone build (QJIEUVF).

As there's the new Android 11 update coming, I'd like to have that and not wait for Vodafone to release its build, as that's notoriously slow.
I tried the official Updater app, to install the XM (non branded) build, but it says the network carrier is different. Seems like the only way is to unlock the bootloader. However, I read that means losing Netflix and Google Pay support?

Now, can I unlock the bootloader, flash the QJIEUXM with XiaoMiToolV2, and then relock the bootloader with Clean and Lock? Would that lead to a softbrick? Any other downside to doing that, such as losing OTA updates?

I tried to find info, but it's really hard to find any reliable information anywhere

Comment: try to flash fastboot ROM on locked bootloader via EDL mode https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/monet